# Azure ARM template Continuous Delivery Release pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am developing CD release pipeline using TFS 2015 update 2 on-prem instance. I'm relying on ARM template to setup Azure website and Azure Sql server. I'm using FTP method for deploying website bits from internal Build server to Azure website. For this website deployment I'm reading the credentials from PublsihingProfile of the newly created website.

Is this a right way or can you suggest a better way? Any comments are appreciated.

P.S. Customer wants to use FTP method and not WebDeploy.

Answer (score 1):

If you really have to use FTP, and the thing you're not happy with is the process/password secret management, you could try this:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=januskamphansen.ftpupload-task

Its a VSTS extension task for release, which works with the vnext build/release system in VSTS or TFS2015 server.  This task lets you put the parameters in against each environment you setup, and mark the passwords as secrets so they wont come out in logs or the UI.

The step basically wraps up the process of doing the ftp bit for you - you may want to do other steps as part of the release.